# Calling an Angular click in a controller from React

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, redux

I have an old Angular1.5 app, quite a large code base.
I'm now using **ngReact** to instance React from within an angular directive.
This is all working correctly. My new react 'sub-app' for want of a better phrase is working ok.

But now I need to call an `ng-click` in part of the old Angular app from React. The Angular ng-click then pops up a modal. The `ng-click` in the controller is in scope so it's available i.e. it's module is loaded into the browser.

Any ideas how to do this ?

I do have **Redux** instanced in Angular using **ngRedux** and available in React, could I dispatch from React and get the controller to respond to this dispatch / action ?

Does this seem ok ?

Comment: Can you bit explain better, I am just getting you are on the way to introduce React with in Angular. I wana share that it will do the same as your rest code does. Anyways, you surely missing on something.

Comment: Yes the Angular app creates a directive that invokes React using ngReact. The Angular app also creates the Redux store using ngRedux. The Redux store is then 'shared' between  Angular and React

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question is yes, I can use Redux and subscribe to the redux state change in the angular controller with something like this

```
  var unsubscribeRedux = $ngRedux.connect(this.mapStateToThis, fireAddTaskEvent )(this);
      $scope.$on('$destroy', unsubscribeRedux);


 this.mapStateToThis = function(state) {
     console.log("fired from react");

       return {
         value: state.addTasks
      };
    }
```

It's crude at the moment, but works